# apply same storyboard in multiple control

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="storyboard.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="all_in_one">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="btn_a">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFCDCDCD"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="#FFED0B00"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FFCDCDCD"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button x:Name="btn_a" Content="A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" Margin="117,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Click="btn_a_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_b" Content="B" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" Margin="187,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn_c" Content="C" Height="56" Margin="257,134,301,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

here i created a storyboard for button a("btn_a").

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }

    private void btn_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard button_animation = (Storyboard)(FindResource("all_in_one"));
        button_animation.Begin();            
    }
}
```

i want apply same storyboard to each other buttons such as btn_b and btn_c in code behind dynamically.

if i click button b,it has to animate and button c as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do this.  That being said, you could do it like this:

```
    private void btnC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = Resources["all_in_one"] as Storyboard;
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(storyboard, "btnC");

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

You need to remove your **Storyboard.TargetName** assignment from your XAML for this to work.

If you need to launch multiple storyboards at once, just call Begin() additional times after calling the Storyboard.SetTargetName function with the new target name.

Comment: Is there a way to do this entirely in XAML? I'm guessing using DataTrigger?